# Java: CopyOnWriteArrayList vs synchronizedList

Tags: java, collections

What is the difference between `CopyOnWritearraylist` and `Collections.synchronizedList(..)`? When should one be preferred over the other.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` list should be used when the number of reads vastly outnumber the number of writes. This is because you are trading unnecessary synchronization for expensive array copying on each write.

For example, when you have a `List` of event listeners in a multi-threaded environment, you'd want to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, because

- events are fired, and hence the list is iterated very often
- event listeners are registered rarely

Comment: Although in slightly different context, but how is CopyOnWriteArrayList different than an unmodifiable List?