# Is CopyOnWriteArrayList enough for keeping shopping cart thread-safe in Servlet Session scope

Tags: java, servlets, collections, concurrency, shopping-cart

Is [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) list enough to use as a collection for shopping-cart. As I understand it is thread-safe and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when during iteration another thread removes a product. For example:

```
    ...
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<Product> products = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<Product>)session.getAttribute("PRODUCTS");
    products.addIfAbsent(aProduct);
    ...
```

P.S. I found synchronization approaches using synchronized (session) {...} but it seams a little ugly when I need synchronize session access everywhere when I work with shopping-cart as offered in [this](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServletCaseStudyPart2.html) article

Comment: Here is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842584/java-copyonwritearraylist-vs-synchronizedlist (Java: CopyOnWriteArrayList vs synchronizedList). I would go with a synchronizedList for many use cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are good to go with CopyOnWriteArrayList  in the scenario you described.
It has sufficient guarantees to work as thread safe Implementations including 
visibility. Yes it  is true that it  gives the snapshot of the data  when you call iterate.
But there is always a race condition, while you remove it before reading or read it before removing.CopyOnWriteArrayList  is a fine implementation 
which can be used where **reads >>> writes**,  which i think is the case in shopping cart use case.

It is just that  while iterating you will not see changes (write operation). You should understand nothing is free, if you want to see the changes while traversing you need to properly synchronize your every iteration with any write operation which is will  compromise perfomance. Trust me you will gain nothing. Most of the concurrent Data structures gives weakly consistent state on iteration see (ConcurrentSkipListSet).
So use either CopyOnWriteArrayList, ConcurrentSkipListSet you are good to go. 
I think sets are better for your use case i.e to avoid duplicate orders ..

Comment: Thank you for answer, I also think that it is consensual approach at least for my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what `CopyOnWriteArrayList` provides.

### It provides you a snapshot and does not give you real time view of backend array.

It weakens the contract of visibility, it says that you will not get `ConcurrentModificationException` but also says that if other thread removes some element, the effect will not be visible to other thread which is iterating maybe, because on addition or removal the original array is not mutated or touched and a new one is created on every operation that mutates the backing array.

> Is CopyOnWriteArrayList list enough to use as a collection for
>   shopping-cart.

*Depends.*

If this behavior is acceptable in your scenario then you can use it, but if you want visibility guarantee you may have to use explicit locking.

Answer (score 0):

> Is CopyOnWriteArrayList list enough to use as a collection for shopping-cart

No because it depends on what you need to synchronize. Think about what must not happen at the same time.

> As I understand it is thread-safe and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException when during iteration another thread removes a product.

You will not get a `ConcurrentModificationException` because every modification you do to the list will create a copy of the list. A thread that iterates will use the most current copy. But that thread can't assume that a product is still actually in the list when it sees it. It might have been removed in the most current version.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe to use "heavier artillery" like following, in all places when accessing to shopping-cart collection.

```
    AtomicReference<List<Product>> productListRef = 
        AtomicReference<List<Product>>)session.getAttribute("PRODUCTS");

    List<Product> oldList;
    List<Product> newList;

    do {
        oldList = productListRef.get();
        newList = new ArrayList<>(oldList);
        newList.add(aProduct);
    } while (!ref.compareAndSet(oldList, newList));
```

Thank a lot for previous answers!